# Database Queries with Ajax without Delay

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

I am not good in Javascript/jQuery and I have a working AJAX DB Query but unfortunately its taking 3 seconds to appear on Homepage. I want to have it shown immidiately and then it will refresh every 30-60 seconds only.

```
var autorefresh = setInterval(
function (){
$('#autorefresh').load('eventlog.php').fadeIn('slow');
}, 30000);
```

the setInterval starts as the pageload is finished and then it takes 30 seconds to appear. Someone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new function which holds your logic
2. Call this function in the load event in jQuery(will execute immediately)
3. Call the same function in the `setInterval` block of code(will execute every x milliseconds)

   ```
   $(function () {

       doStuff();

       var autorefresh = setInterval(
       function () {
           doStuff();
       }, 30000);

       function doStuff() {
           alert('doStuff() fired...');
           $('#autorefresh').load('eventlog.php').fadeIn('slow');
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Test and Aproved - Thank you very much. Its so simple but I dont got it by myself...